# Jquery form dropdown not working

Tags: jquery

i'm having a major struggle getting this jquery code to drop certain form fields down based on user option selected. It only drops the last option (4) down properly while the others drop down and then slide back up immediately.

HTML FILES USED BELOW:

```
<h4>Lesson Form</h4>
<form action="mailer.php" data-validate="parsley" method="post" >
    <p><strong>Full Name<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
    <input name="cf_name" data-required="true"  class="send" type="text" />
    <p><strong>Email Address<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
    <input name="cf_email" data-required="true" data-type="email" class="send" type="text" />
    <p><strong>Cellphone No.<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
    <input name="cf_cell" data-required="true" class="send" type="text" />

    <p><strong>Instrument Type<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
    <select name="cf_instrument" size="1" class="option" >
        <option value="Piano">Piano</option>
        <option value="Vocals">Vocals</option>
        <option value="Guitar">Guitar</option>
        <option value="Bass">Bass</option>
        <option value="Flute">Flute</option></select>

    <p><strong>Lesson Type<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
    <select name="cf_package_type" size="1" class="option">
        <option value="Beginner Lesson - R100">Beginner Lesson - R100</option>
        <option value="Advanced Lesson - R130">Advanced Lesson - R130</option>
        <option value="Professional Lesson - R160">Professional Lesson - R160</option></select>

    <p><strong>No. of Lessons<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
    <select id="number-of-lessons" name="cf_number" size="1" class="option" onchange='test()'>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
        <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
        <option name="3" value="3">3</option>
        <option name="4" value="4">4</option></select>

    <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
    <p><strong>Lesson Date & Time<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
    <p class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
        <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true" />
        <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true" /> to
        <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true" /></p>

    <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
    <p id="lesson-2" class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
        <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true"  />
        <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true"  /> to
        <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true"  /></p>

    <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
    <p id="lesson-3" class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
        <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true"  />
        <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true"  /> to
        <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true"  /></p>

    <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
    <p id="lesson-4" class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
        <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true"  />
        <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true"  /> to
        <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true"  /></p> 

    <!-- HIDDEN FIELD - HONEYPOT ANTI_SPAM -->
    <input id="website" class="using" name="website" type="text"  />
    <!-- END -->
    <input name="Submit" class="submit" value="Book Now" type="submit" /></form>
```

JQUERY SCRIPT FILES USED BELOW:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#lesson-2").css("display","none");
        $("#lesson-3").css("display","none");
        $("#lesson-4").css("display","none");
        $(".option").click(function(){
            if ($('option[name=2]:checked').val() == "2" ) {
                $("#lesson-2").slideDown("fast"); 
            } else {
                $("#lesson-2").slideUp("fast"); 
            }
            if ($('option[name=3]:checked').val() == "3" ) {
                $("#lesson-2").slideDown("fast"); 
                $("#lesson-3").slideDown("fast"); 
            } else {
                $("#lesson-2").slideUp("fast"); 
                $("#lesson-3").slideUp("fast");  
            }
            if ($('option[name=4]:checked').val() == "4" ) {
                $("#lesson-2").slideDown("fast"); 
                $("#lesson-3").slideDown("fast"); 
                $("#lesson-4").slideDown("fast"); 
            } else {
                $("#lesson-2").slideUp("fast"); 
                $("#lesson-3").slideUp("fast");
                $("#lesson-4").slideUp("fast");   
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle and let us know the exact issue instead of full code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7V8Jd/ there we go! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below fiddle. The logic was wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/7V8Jd/1/

1. Instead of `$(".option").click(function(){` use `$(".option").change(function(){`
2. If else logic seems not proper to me as well.

Comment: Welcome ! If this helped you please done forget the mark the answer as correct. :)